# Python - Access a model, with a name that is dependant on a variable value

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access a model, with a name that is dependant on a variable value.

If have a series of models based on a country identifier. e.g. Student_???  where ??? is the country identifier.

If I want to print out details of each student for each country, is there a way of looping through the code to access each model dynamically. I could perform the task through an if statement, but that would require hardcoding each country code into the program, which I want to avoid.

As an example. My views.py looks like:

```
mystudentcountry = {'AU', 'US', 'UK', 'EU'}

for country in mystudentcountry:

    mystudent = Student_AU.objects.all()

    for student in mystudent:
        print(f'{student.name} is {student.age} years old and studies in {country}')
```

On the third line of code "mystudent = Student_AU.objects.all()" is it possible to replace the "AU" with each country as identified in the loop.

Thank You for your support.

Comment: is `Student_AU` in a package? how do you import it? there may be a very elegant way to get this.

Comment: I currently export it as follows:

Comment: from .models import Student_AU   Not ideal, as I would ideally import this dynamically also. I have yet to look into how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use getattr, but it may require a bit of organization in your models.

if you have a folder called `models`, and inside that folder you have `students_au.py`, `students_us.py`, ..., you can create a `__init__.py` file that has:

```
from students_au import students_AU # imports the actual model frm the file
from students_us import students_US
from students_uk import students_UK
```

Then in your `views.py`

```
import models

mystudentcountry = {'AU', 'US', 'UK', 'EU'}

for country in mystudentcountry:
    # this is the magic
    # getattr(obj, "name_of_attribute") is the same as obj.name_of_attribute
    country_model = getattr(models, "students_%s" % country) 

    mystudent = country_model.objects.all()

    for student in mystudent:
        print(f'{student.name} is {student.age} years old and studies in {country}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put students and countries in a dictionary and then iterate over the dictionary items:

```
student_dict = {Student_AU: 'AU', Student_US: 'US', Student_UK: 'UK'}

for student, country in student_dict.items():
    mystudent = student.objects.all()
    for i in mystudent:
        print(f'{i.name} is {i.age} years old and studies in {country}')
```

This should work unless `Student_AU` and other objects are mutable, e.g. lists.

Answer (score 0):

If it is static list of countries, you can create your custom Manager.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/

Example:

```
class StudentsFromAU(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(country='AU')

class Book(models.Model):
    # your model description

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    au_students = DahlBookManager() # The specific manager.
```

Now you can get them like:

```
Student.au_students.all()
```